# "Loading leaks" on LeakCanary is really slow, what alternatives do I have?

Tags: android, leakcanary, fbflipper

Every time I want to look into a leak, I click on the notification of the leak and it takes a really long time to load, like enough time that I usually forget about it.

Flipper never loads the leak list when I attempt to look at them there.

So what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to the latest beta releases, this is a known issue in 1.X that has since been fixed

Comment: Oh wow that was so much faster, thanks. Too bad flipper doesn't work still but I can live without that.

Answer (score 0):

check out leak canary for the android devices, just put the dependency in graddle